# Improvement of SQL UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I need improvement of this SQL UPDATE query. The query has to only update the first row, but I suspect that it uses a lot of power on running through all rows and running the subquery for all rows, because when using big databases it it very slow. Any suggestions?

```
    UPDATE leads l
    SET status='processing', processor='$processor' 
    WHERE pool IN ($pools) AND status='active'
    ORDER BY (SELECT count(*) FROM calls c WHERE c.lead = l.id), id ASC
    LIMIT 1
```

UPDATE

The slowness is indeed caused by the subselect. Typical there might be 2000-3000 matches in the leads-table. The easiest way would be to build in a column in the leads-table that counts calls manually so I wouldn't need the subselect, but it is a running site where these changes need to be made, so it would mess up the order if I added the column now.

But I suppose it is the only way to avoid the large subselect.

Comment: It sounds like you're missing an index? Put `EXPLAIN` in front of your query to see what it's doing ...

Comment: tried `EXPLAIN EXTENDED UPDATE ...`? `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` returns some more information about what happens exactly when running the UPDATE query.

Answer (score 0):

For me - slowness comes from subselect. For every `pool` you query all `calls` to calculate number of them. First be sure that `calls.lead` is indexed. You can keep that counter in `pool`, and have triggers to keep that real. Other option is to keep that info inside index, but I can't tell how to use that on MySQL, a specially on unknown version

Comment: Indeed. I'm not quite sure I understand your suggestions - could you explain a bit more?

Comment: `pool IN ($pools) AND status='active'` - for each of them you are calling `SELECT count(*) FROM calls c WHERE c.lead = l.id` - to sort them. First be sure that `c.lead = l.id` uses index. If that is still too slow - add `count(*) FROM calls c WHERE c.lead = l.id` as separate column in `pool`, and update it via triggers

Answer (score 0):

Creating a multiple column index on leads-table for the columns `pool` and `status` would be the easiest way to speed up your update. But how many rows are really in your lead table? And how many rows are fitting your where clause?

**Multiple Column Index**

```
 ALTER TABLE your_schema.leads
    ADD INDEX faster_update(pool,status) ;
```

Also why would you only update a limited amount of rows that match your criteria? You might want to give more info on your case to get the most helpfull answer. And using a subselect on a 'big' table to order it before updating sounds like a bad idea regarding execution time as the order by could easily take more time than the update itself.

In case your don't know if an index is used, use the following code to analyze your query :

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM your_schema.leads 
    WHERE pool IN ($pools) AND status='active'
    ORDER BY (SELECT count(*) FROM calls c WHERE c.lead = l.id), id ASC
```

Or just post the result here